# Symfony 3.4 tests failing with "logout_on_user_change" option set to "true"

Tags: php, symfony

I am having problems with the `logout_on_user_change` option set to true (which is default behavior in Symfony 4). 
But only when running unit tests. In my dev environment everything (login, logout etc.) works fine.
But my unit tests which are trying to log in are failing. The authentication is not working anymore. I guess there must be something happening with the user in the background which leads to automatic logout due to this option.

I already updated the `serialize()` method of the user entity, as suggested there: [symfony 3.4 "Refreshing a deauthenticated user is deprecated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698006/symfony-3-4-refreshing-a-deauthenticated-user-is-deprecated)

Anyone having the same problem?

PROBLEM SOLVED:
Found the solution myself:
This lead myself in the right direction: [Token was deauthenticated after trying to refresh it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675301/token-was-deauthenticated-after-trying-to-refresh-it/47676103#47676103)

Which is also important to note is that the checks in `isEqualTo()` need to use the same fields as the `serialize()` functions:

So in my case this works with `logout_on_user_change` enabled:

```
/**
 * @see \Serializable::serialize()
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(
        array(
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password,
        $this->salt
        )
    );
}

/**
 * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password,
        $this->salt
    ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
}

public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
{
    if ($this->id !== $user->getId()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->salt !== $user->getSalt()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->email !== $user->getEmail()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @AlisterBulman Indeed it is related, I linked to the same post. But I added an important note, without it didn´t worked for me!

Comment: @Pointi just a note it is better if you "answer" your own question then edit it with the answer. That allows the question to show it has an answer, and if anything changes in the future for a new answer to be presented for the question.

Comment: @MEmerson true! Will do it in the future. Thanks.